# Popular books written by great mathematicians

Tags: soft-question, books, gm.general-mathematics, popularization

I read:

H. Poincare. Value of science

F. Klein. Development of Mathematics in the 19th Century

J.E. Littlewood. A Mathematicians Miscellany

G.H. Hardy. A Mathematician’s Apology

R. Courant, H.Robbins. What Is Mathematics?

V.I. Arnold. Mathematical Understanding of Nature: Essays on Amazing Physical Phenomena and Their Understanding by Mathematicians.

What else? The author must be an influent mathematician and the book must not be "just another popular math book".

Comment: André Weil's "Souvenirs d'apprentissage" (English translation: The Apprenticeship of a Mathematician) is a book I like.

Answer (score 7):

*Geometry and the Imagination* by David Hilbert and Stefan Cohn-Vossen.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if it counts, because not a math book, but

- Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll (Charles Lutwidge Dodgson)

Comment: For Martin Gardner's commentary on the recreational mathematics aspects, see "The Annotated Alice" http://www.amazon.com/Annotated-Alice-Definitive-Lewis-Carroll/dp/0393048470/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1422487507&sr=1-1